# A problem about expected value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, problem-solving, expected-value

Some students have a list of processes to execute sequentially but the running of a process may fail during execution, so the probability that a process $x$ will be executed successfully is $Px$.

Assume that the execution takes one second to be run to compute the answer for each process, if the program crashes, it will take 3 seconds more for the students to re-run it and in this case, the execution should be re-run starting from the first process.

You are given the probability that each process will be executed successfully, What is the number of seconds expected to pass all processes without crushing ?

I couldn't figure out how to determine the expected value to run all the processes successfully. I know it is something like $E(x) =  Px \times (1) + (1 - Px) \times (1 + 3 + E(x)) $ and I think it is depending on the previous process to be run successfully but I failed to get the right answer..

Comment: You that there are a number of processes that must run sequentially.  Do they each have the same probability of failure?  Also, I'm not sure what happens when a process crashes.  Suppose the fourth process crashed.  We know the first three took $3$ seconds.  For how long did the fourth run prior to crashing?

Comment: no processes have not to share the same probability they could be different and if the fourth process crashed just we need to add 3 seconds to the hole time to restart the execution of all processes from zero i hope that i made it clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the expected number of seconds waited be $E(X)$. Then the expected value is given by
$$E(X)=Px(1)+(1-Px)(3+E(Y)+E(X))$$
Where $Y$ is the amount of time taken for the process to crash. I assume that this is uniformly distributed between $0$ and $1$, so $E(Y)=0.5$.
Solving this then gives
$$E(X)=\frac{3.5-2.5Px}{Px}=\frac{7-5Px}{2Px}$$

Comment: Thank you so much your answer helped me a lot ! i just made a little modification to get the right answer i added 1 because we should take into account the wasted time of the execution of the failed process so it becomes E(X)=Px(1)+(1−Px)(1+3+E(Y)+E(X))

Comment: We know from the OP that $E(Y)=1$. The $E(X)$ calculated here is the expected time it takes for the **first** process to succeed..

Answer (score 1):

We can write

$$
\begin{align}
E(x) &= \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} \left(\text{probability that the process terminates succesfully after $(i+1)$ attempts}\right)\\
&\times(\text{amount of time needed to complete the process in exactly $(i+1)$-th attempts}) =\\
&=\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}\left((1-P_x)^i\cdot P_x)\cdot ((1+3)\cdot i+1)\right)=\\
&=P_x \cdot \left(\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}4i\cdot (1-P_x)^i + \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} (1-P_x)^i\right)=\\
&=P_x\cdot \left( 4\cdot \frac{1-P_x}{P_{x}^2}+\frac{1}{1-(1-P_x)} \right)=\\
&=4\cdot\frac{1-P_x}{P_{x}}+1=\\
&=\frac{4-3P_x}{P_{x}}.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

So, like in the other answers, I will assume that all processes succeed with the same probability $p:=P_x$. Let $E:=E(X)$ denote the desired expected value. Also, to see the influence of the delay after a crash ($3$ seconds), let's call it $d$. The probability for completing all processes successfully after $n$ seconds is $p^n$. If the whole sequence crashes at process $k \le n$, which will happen with a probability of $(1-p)p^{k-1}$, it already took $k$ seconds and will take another $d+E$ to complete the whole task successfully. In total, we have:

\begin{align}
E &= (1+d+E)(1-p) + (2+d+E)(1-p)p + \cdots + (n+d+E)(1-p)p^{n-1} + np^n\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+d+k+E)(1-p)p^{k} + np^n\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+d+k+E)p^{k} - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+d+k+E)p^{k+1} + np^n\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+d+k+E)p^{k} - \sum_{k=1}^{n}(d+k+E)p^{k} + np^n\\
&= 1+d+E + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}p^{k} - (d+n+E)p^{n} + np^n\\
&= 1+d+E + \sum_{k=1}^{n}p^{k} - (1+d+E)p^{n}\\
&= E(1-p^n) + (1+d)(1-p^n) + p\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}p^{k}
\end{align}

Solving this for $E$, we get

\begin{align}
E &= \frac{(1+d)(1-p^n)}{p^n} + \frac{p(1-p^n)}{(1-p)p^n} = \frac{(1+d)(1-p^n)(1-p) + p(1-p^n)}{(1-p)p^n}\\
&= \frac{(1-p+d-dp+p)(1-p^n)}{(1-p)p^n} = \frac{(1+d-dp)(1-p^n)}{(1-p)p^n}\\
&= \frac{1-p^n}{p^n} \left(d+\frac{1}{1-p}\right)
\end{align}

**Added:**

For $n=1$, this results in the formula that [@simonet](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3127987/640973) gave.

If the probabilities of the processes differ, the formula will not be that simple. For example, if we have two processes with probabilities $p_1$ and $p_2$ to succeed, and the students have to successfully complete process $1$ first, it's easy to see that the expected total time to successfully complete both processes becomes $$ E=\frac{1-p_1p_2}{p_1p_2}\left(d+\frac{1+p_1}{1-p_1p_2}\right)$$ This is clearly not symmetric, and we see that to minimize the expected time, we'd be better off to take the risky process first.